# NotAMockException in Junit5

Tags: mockito, junit5

I am facing a problem in my test after migrating to junit5. It says that parameter of verifyZeroInteractions is not mock object but actually it is a mock object. I receive NotAMockException.

I cannot understand why I am getting it although it is a mock object.

My test:

```
@BeforeEach
 public void setup() {
    mockObject = mock(MyObject.class);
    controller = new MyController(mockObject);
}

@Test
public void myTest() {

    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> controller.search(searchRequest));

    verifyZeroInteractions(mockObject);
}
```

Comment: Can you show imports, annotations on test class and on relevant fields, and complete stack trace?

Comment: Also, run the code in debugger and inspect mockObject - if it is not a mock, than what is it?

Comment: I debugged the code, it is actually mock. that is why it is weird and I do not understand reason